# Questions about calling ApplyTransaction(go-ethereum)

Tags: go-ethereum

I'm making a smart contract fuzzer now.

I use core.ApplyTransaction in go-ethereum.

but when I call `core.ApplyTransaction` in my go source, the error: `error: invalid opcode: PUSH0` occurs.

My EVM bytecode is 0.8.20, and go-ethereum is the latest version.

but core.ApplyTransaction does not appear to be called to the latest evm.

Is there a way to set the evm version to shanghai?

Answer (score 0):

The EVM version is determined by:

1. blocks specified in the genesis.json
2. conditions specified in the code @ `params\config.go`

The latest version of `geth` has a function `func (c *ChainConfig) IsShanghai(time uint64) book` which determines whether or not we're in Shanghai based on the timestamp (using the `isTimestampForked()` function).

You can change the logic of this function, for example

```
// IsShanghai returns whether time is either equal to the Shanghai fork time or greater.
func (c *ChainConfig) IsShanghai(time uint64) bool {
    if c.ChainID == nil {
        return false
    }
    return c.ChainID.Cmp(big.NewInt(<your-chain-id>) == 0 
           || isTimestampForked(c.ShanghaiTime, time)
}
```

The Shanghai fork introduces many changes, not just the `PUSH0` instruction. If you'd like to only add that (without moving onto Shanghai) you can add the instruction into the EVM instruction set in `core\vm\jump_table.go` by calling `enable3855(&instructionSet)`. Make sure the `core\vm\eips.go` is up to date, i.e. `funct enabled3855(jt *JumpTable)` is defined